# objective c plist trailing zeros

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

Newbie here,

In a plist file I am trying to enter a type number as 1.00 but it removes the trailing zeros. 1.50 becomes 1.5. Do I have to enter it as type string or add the zeros in code once I retrieve it from the plist?

If I change the type to string it would work but I would have to change all my other code to convert it once it's retrieved, correct?

Comment: Why do you need 1.50 or 1.00 instead of 1.5 or 1?

Answer (score 2):

The plist type for numbers are NSNumber. So your input is getting "formatted" in a way.
So yes, parsing it to a string is one way, the other is to use NSNumberFormatter.